# Count number of rown against each id in other table contains the same id as foreign key using active records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have the fowllowing two tables from where i need complete list of Racks and count the no of foreign keys rack_id matches with the rack.id and id of racks not matched with any of the rack_id it should retun 0

Modal

```
function getRacksList()
    {
        $this->db->select('rack.name as name, rack.details as details, rack.id as id');
        $this->db->from('books');
        $this->db->join('rack', 'rack.id = books.rack_id', 'left');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }
```

```
Controller
 function rackDetails(){

        $data['racks'] = $this->rack_model->getRacksList();

        print_r($data['racks']);
        die();
    }
```

Results i am getting

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Software Engineering [details] => This Book Rack is for Software Engineering Books [id] => 1 )
 [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Computer Sciences [details] => This rack is for Computer Sciences Books [id] => 2 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Software Engineering [details] => This Book Rack is for Software Engineering Books [id] => 1 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Software Engineering [details] => This Book Rack is for Software Engineering Books [id] => 1 ) 
)
```

Racks

```
id    rack_name
1     rack one
2     rack two
3     rack three
4     rack four
5     rack five
```

Books

```
id    book_name   rack_id
1     book one      1
2     book two      1
3     book three    2
4     book four     2
5     book five     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, a solution would be to `LEFT JOIN` the `rack` table with th `books` table and use aggregation to count how many books belong to each rack.

Here is a code snippet that uses raw sql :

```
function getRacksList()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT rack.name, rack.details, rack.id, COUNT(books.rack_id) as books_count
        FROM rack
        LEFT JOIN books ON rack.id = books.rack_id
        GROUP BY rack.name, rack.details, rack.id
    ");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: @KamiTahir: just fixed a typo in my answer (`$query` was not declared). Does this work for you now?